# Can you suggest me a good book for self-study of analytic geometry 1?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-geometry, self-learning

I'm stuyding mathematics *alone*, but I plan to enter in the university in the near future, I went to the university website and it suggests Analytic Geometry 1 as part of their curricula, the topics I'll need to cover are in this [PDF File](http://pt.scribd.com/doc/110704191/Geom-Analitica), sorry if I didn't translate it but I did so because I believe you won't have much trouble since there are a lot of cognates.

I'm aware that there may be other questions asking the same thing, but I'm afraid on the topics being different because I'm from Brazil (Maybe there's something more, something less, don't know). This book should also be adequate for self-study due to my current conditions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't open the PDF file but if you want to study co-ordinate geometry, I recommend

> The Elements of Co ordinate Geometry by SL LONEY

This is the best book I have read for understanding the basics of this subject.

Comment: I switched the link, it's on scribd now. If you wanna try.

Comment: The book you suggested is very good, thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

Calculus and Analytic Geometry by George B. Thomas is a classic introduction. There have been a lot of editions, which do vary some in their content, so be careful if you buy a copy to buy one that has Analytic Geometry in the title.